# Asus S400CA with Philips 220SW monitor screen resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an Asus S400CA notebook running on Windows 8.1 and connecting it to my external monitor Philips 220SW. The screen resolution is stuck at 1024x768 and the dropdown is disabled so I cannot change it to the correct resolution which is 1680x1050.
I tested the monitor with another Lenovo notebook (on WIndows 7) and it works fine there.

Here are the screenshots that I see when trying to change the resolution

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to install Windows 7 drivers on Windows 8, reinstalling graphics drivers, reboot, etc. I decided to change the VGA cable (had a spare one). That seemed to do the trick, despite not making any sense. (As described in the Question, it worked with a Lenovo laptop using the same cable and monitor)

TLDR: Use a different VGA cable.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the video driver will let you change resolutions that are not available natively. Check if you have the proper graphics driver.